# Spring - BeanPostProcessor interface

Tags: spring

I just started learning spring. While implementing a sample program I got a problem and thought of checking in this forum to get the answer.

### Follwoing is spring.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org    /dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="triangle" class="org.springdemo.Triangle" autowire="byName">
    </bean>

    <bean id="employee" class="org.springdemo.emp.Employee" autowire="byName">
    
    </bean>

    <bean id="address" class="org.springdemo.emp.Address">
        <property name="city" value="PUNE"></property>
        <property name="street" value="MH"></property>
        <property name="pin" value="411013"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="customerDAO" class="org.mykong.springdb.Customer">

    </bean>

</beans>
```

### Here is my client program:

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = 
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

        Customer customer = (Customer) context.getBean("customerDAO");
 System.out.println(customer.getBeanName());

    }
```

### My Customer bean:

```
     public class Customer implements BeanNameAware, BeanPostProcessor{

            private String name;
        private int age;

        protected Customer() {

        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public void setAge(int age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    
        public String toString() {
            return "Customer id : "  + " , Name : "  + this.name + " , Age: " +     this.age;
        }

        public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory arg0) throws BeansException {
        
        
        }

        private String beanName = null;
        public void setBeanName(String name) {
            this.beanName = name;
        }

        public String getBeanName() {
            return beanName;
        }

        public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String arg1)
                throws BeansException {
        
            System.out.println(" IN : postProcessAfterInitialization - bean         initialized" + bean.getClass() );
            return bean;
        }

        public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String arg1)
                throws BeansException {

            System.out.println(" IN : postProcessBeforeInitialization "  );
            return bean;
        }
        }
```

Question1: As my spring.xml has the configuration about 4 beans. But output comes for only three beans (except customerDAO). Why?

Questions2: What if I just want the before and after process intitialization methods to be called for only customerDAO ?
It might be so simple? I am not sure. But please respond with answers. Thanks in advance

### output:

IN : postProcessBeforeInitialization
IN : postProcessAfterInitialization - bean initializedclass org.springdemo.Triangle
IN : postProcessBeforeInitialization
IN : postProcessAfterInitialization - bean initializedclass org.springdemo.emp.Address
IN : postProcessBeforeInitialization
IN : postProcessAfterInitialization - bean initializedclass org.springdemo.emp.Employee
customerDAO

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of `BeanPostProcessor` is to intercept initialization of other beans. It cannot intercept its own initialization, because Spring guarantees that post-processor is fully initialized when its post-process methods are called.

If you need to perform an action after initialization of this very bean, you can do one of the following:

- Implement `InitializingBean` and override `afterPropertiesSet`
- Use `init-method` attribute of `<bean>` to specify name of the method to be called
- Annotate the method to be called with `@PostConstruct`

Comment: Thanks for the info, I am really not clear with the second point you mentioned. But my question is I want to restrict calling the methods postProcessAfterInitialization() and postProcessBeforeInitialization() to a particular bean.